# Undefined index - array offset | PHP form | index appears to exist but states it does not

Tags: php, forms, rest

My `PHP` script does several things interacting with a `REST API`.

- Creates an access token
- Creates a new conversation using that access token

Once the conversation is created, the script will upload an image to associate with that conversation. This is where things have me a little jammed up.

**my form code**

```
<form action="news_feed.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
                        </div>
                        <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sb_title-help-block">
                        <div id="sb_title-help-block" class="form-text">
                            This will set the title of your binder
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="height: 25px">
                        </div>
                        <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sb_subject-help-block">
                        <div id="sb_subject-help-block" class="form-text">
                            This will set the subject of your Binder     
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="height: 25px"></div>
                        <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sb_message-help-block" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
                        <div id="sb_message-help-block" class="form-text">
                            This will add a message to your binder upon creation     
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="height: 25px"></div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="image" class="form-label">Image</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="image" name="image">
                        </div>
                        <div id="sb-image-help-block" class="form-text">
                            This will add an image to your binder      
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="row" style="height: 25px"></div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Create Newsfeed">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**initial code to grab image data**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name       = $_FILES['image']['name'];  
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

var_dump($_POST);

$sbuploadurl = ''.$api_url.$org_id. '/binders/' . $sub_binder['data']['id'] .'/coverupload?access_token='.$token['access_token'].'';

if(! isset($_POST['image'])) {
    echo 'You have a file in the array';
} else {
    die('Image isnt found');
}
```

The above code does return `Image isnt found`   If I change `isset($_POST['image']` to `isset($_FILES['image']` the following is returned: `You have a file in the array`. I dont know if its just reporting that its gotten the image name as seen below or if it actually has the file.

My `var_dump($_POST);` outputs the following:

```
array (size=5)
  'title' => string 'Title' (length=5)
  'subject' => string 'Subject' (length=7)
  'message' => string 'Message' (length=7)
  'image' => string 'megaman_avatar.png' (length=18)
  'submit' => string 'Create Newsfeed' (length=15)
```

It appears that the index I am grabbing is there.

Additionally I do have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set on the form itself.

**error being output when script is run**

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: image in
PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

My limited knowledge of arrays, would tell me this is not multi-dimensional. From what I know also, I believe you would just, in this case, refer to the index in the array without having to add the name of the array. I say this based on the fact that in my `$sbuploadurl` I did have to do this to grab the `id` that was being returned by the API.

Every example I have seen in regard to uploading an image via a form shows the format that I am using:

```
 $name       = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

My understanding is that `image` is the name of the `form field` and `name` is the name of the file itself. Am I correct in this?

There is something I am clearly missing here. I believe this should be pretty straight foward. Wondering if doing this with JavaScript would be less of a pull.

Comment: Have you included  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag? If not you'll get the file name but not the file, so your `$_FILES` array will be empty.

Comment: I do actually. That was the one thing I forgot to post.

Comment: Can you post your entire `<form>`? You don't seem to be getting the `$_FILES` array, and I suspect the problem is in the form.

Comment: You are vardumping`$_POST` but the code is referring  to`$_FILES` - they are not the same variable. Look at the same variable the code, this error explains the title question. It’s also worth bearing in mind language error messages are basically always accurate - guide debugging efforts around that